# Is there a platform where I can use Bitcoins to gamble online?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

And do I have to signup for these services and/or verify my identity?

Answer (score 1):

There are several. One of the first and most established is [Satoshi Dice](https://www.satoshidice.com).

As far as I read you need not verify your identity but I haven't used it myself.